# How to parse string to specific pattern in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an `angular` component in which i have 4 fields `customerName`, `startDate`, `startTime`. Now i have 4rth field as `textarea` in which i am showing user that what message would be sent over message email or sms. So i have a string defined in my component like this

```
emailConent = 'Hi [customer_name],↵↵Your appointment has been scheduled for [start_date] at [start_time]'
```

So on component load i generate a message by replace all text within `[]` to respective values of input field. Like i replace `[customer_name]` with the value of `customerName` like wise i replace `[start_date]` with `startDate` and so on. So my template becomes like this

```
Hi John Doe,

Your appointment has been scheduled for 30-Mar-20 at 03:00 pm.  
Please confirm your appointment.
```

And this template is visible in a textarea field and user is seeing this template. And also user can change this text like user can add additonal text in this text area.

So what i want is that if user add further data in text area like this

```
Hi John Doe,

Your appointment has been scheduled for 30-Mar-20 at 03:00 pm.  
Please confirm your appointment. Please be on time there
```

So you can see that `Please be on time there` is text added by user in text area. So what i want is to parse it back to my tags format like this

```
'Hi [customer_name],↵↵Your appointment has been scheduled for [start_date] at [start_time]. Please be on time there'
```

I just want to get that addtional text that user has added in `textarea`.

How can i acheive that in `angular` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic diff finder I can think of. You can modify the diff calculator.

```js
function getEmail(customer_name, start_date, end_date) {
  const emailTemplate = `Hi ${customer_name},

Your appointment has been scheduled for ${start_date} at ${end_date} pm.
Please confirm your appointment.`;
  return emailTemplate;
}

const myString = getEmail("John Doe", "30-Mar-20", "03:00");

// after modify
const userString = `Hi John Doe,

Your appointment has been scheduled for 30-Mar-20 at 03:00 pm.  
Please confirm your appointment. Please be on time there.`;
let diff = "";
const myStringArray = myString.split(/\n/);
userString.split(/\n/).some((line, index) => {
  const originalLine = myStringArray[index].trim();
  const modifiedLine = line.trim();
  if (modifiedLine !== originalLine) {
    diff =
      originalLine.length > modifiedLine
        ? originalLine.replace(modifiedLine, "")
        : modifiedLine.replace(originalLine, "");
    return false;
  }
});
console.log(diff);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use Template literals string it's supported in typescript.
Instead of using `'` you should use ```.
If you want to print your variable it's very easy this way :

```
`Hi ${customer_name},

 Your appointment has been scheduled for ${start_date} at ${start_time}. Please be on time there`
```

Comment: You know, someone is trying to help you. 
You could say, thanks man but you didn't get my question correctly, but why giving me a negative point? I could edit my answer at the end you know.